# Puzzle: find number in a given row and column in 2-dimensional array where no number may occur twice

Tags: language-agnostic, multidimensional-array

We have a two-dimensional array with the number 0 in the upper left corner. The rest of the array is then filled with numbers so that each index contains the smallest positive integer possible that already exists neither on the same row or column.

Example:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
  1  0  3  2  5  4  7  6  9  8 11 10 13 12 15 14 17 16
  2  3  0  1  6  7  4  5 10 11  8  9 14 15 12 13 18 19
  3  2  1  0  7  6  5  4 11 10  9  8 15 14 13 12 19 18
  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3 12 13 14 15  8  9 10 11 20 21
  5  4  7  6  1  0  3  2 13 12 15 14  9  8 11 10 21 20
  6  7  4  5  2  3  0  1 14 15 12 13 10 11  8  9 22 23
  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8 23 22
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 24 25
  9  8 11 10 13 12 15 14  1  0  3  2  5  4  7  6 25 24
 10 11  8  9 14 15 12 13  2  3  0  1  6  7  4  5 26 27
 11 10  9  8 15 14 13 12  3  2  1  0  7  6  5  4 27 26
 12 13 14 15  8  9 10 11  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3 28 29
 13 12 15 14  9  8 11 10  5  4  7  6  1  0  3  2 29 28
 14 15 12 13 10 11  8  9  6  7  4  5  2  3  0  1 30 31
 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 31 30
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  0  1
 17 16 19 18 21 20 23 22 25 24 27 26 29 28 31 30  1  0
```

Given the row and the column in such array, I need to be able to find the number in the specified index in less than one second on a relatively new desktop PC (for row and column less than a million). My brute-force attempts so far have been so futile that it's clearly not the way I want to go with this. Presumably there must be a way to find out the number in question, in linear time (?), that doesn't require computing all the preceding numbers in the array.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bitwise XOR. Proving that might be a challenge, especially the "smallest" part.

Comment: Well spotted @Jan: it looks like the value at any given location is just `row XOR col`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: thank you so much, your comment was invaluable. All the hours I've been trying to figure this out, bitwise operations didn't come to my mind once. I'm not sure if that is the only solution for this puzzle, but definitely the most elegant! You may go ahead and post that as an answer so I can get it accepted.

Comment: @user1704650 I'm trying to prove it's the XOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observation shows that the operator is the bitwise `XOR` (represent each operand as a binary number, XOR together the corresponding bits, read as binary).

Now on to prove it *is* the XOR:

---

Since the XOR with one argument fixed is a bijection on the other argument, the "that exists neither on the same row or column" is satisfied.

Now it just suffices to prove the "smallest" part, namely that any lower value already occurs if we reduce either operand:

```
foreach A >= 0, B >= 0, F >= 0:
  (A xor B > F) => (exists D: D xor B = F) or (exists E: A xor E = F)
```

or equivalently

```
foreach 0 <= A, 0 <= B, 0 <= F < (A XOR B)
  (exists D: D xor B = F) or (exists E: A xor E = F)
```

*Note that we are no longer concerned about our operator, we're proving the minimality of XOR.*

Define `C = A xor B`

if `A = 0`, `B = 0`, then minimality is satisfied.

Now, if `A` and `B` have the same magnitude (the same bit length), then clearing the top bit of both will not change `C`. Clearing the top bit is a translation towards the origin in the matrix, so if a smaller value exists above or to the left after translation, it is at the same relative position before the translation.

`A` and `B` must have a different magnitude to be a counter-example. `XOR` (as well as the operator under consideration) are symmetric, so assume `A > B`.

If `F` is of greater magnitude than `A`, then it's not smaller, and thus it's not a counter-example.

If `F` has the same magnitude as `A`, then clear the highest bit in `A` and in `F`. This is a translation in the table. It changes the values, but not their ordering, so if a smaller value exists above or to the left after translation, it is at the same relative position before the translation.

If `F` has a smaller magnitude than `A`, then, by the pigeonhole principle and the properties of XOR, there exists a `D` with a smaller magnitude than `A` such that `D xor B = F`.

---

summary: The proof that XOR satisfies the conditions imposed onto the solution follows from the symmetries of XOR, its magnitude-preserving properties and its bijection properties. We can find each smaller element than `A xor B` by reducing `A`, `B` and the challenge until they're all zero or of different magnitude (at which point we apply the pigeonhole principle to prove the challenge can be countered without actually countering it).